# Verify that $\sqrt z$ is analytic using the Cauchy–Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, cauchy-riemann-equations

For a Mathematical Methods class I am taking this year, we started off with Complex Analysis. In one of the problem sets we were tasked to show that the complex-valued function $ f(z)= \sqrt z  $ satisfies the Cauchy–Riemann equations and is thus analytic. I made good progress, but I couldn't see how it was satisfied.

**Here is my approach:**

1. if we take $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$, then $\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{x+iy}=a+ib$ (say) as $\mathbb{C}$ is a field we will have a complex number after taking the square root anyway.
2. From there it was trivial to show that $a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ and $b=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$, where we pick the signs such that $ab$ corresponds to sgn$(y)$. From this I have that my original function is thus: $$f(z)=\sqrt z=\pm\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}+i\cdot\pm\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$$
   thus I can split the complex valued function into two parts:
   $$f(z)=\sqrt z=u(x,y)+i(v(x,y));\\  u(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}},\; v(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$$
3. *Now for the partial derivatives*;
   I went through the mechanics and found that:
   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} ; \; \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\pm\frac{y}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$
   &&
   $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-(\pm)\frac{\sqrt{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} ; \; \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\pm\frac{y}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Afterwards, I fail to see how this implies that $u_x=v_y, u_y=-v_x$ I dont think thusfar I have made any major mistakes, however, from this point on, how can I conclude that yes the CR-equations are satisfied? I also tried using the CR-equations in polar form applied to the polar form of $f(z)$ but to no avail.

Comment: I think all 4 of my partial derivatives are correct in form, [Here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/partial-derivative-calculator) all 4 can be verified to be true.

Comment: You cannot show it is analytic whilst using $\pm$ notation. $\pm$ gives a multivalued function: to show the single values function $\sqrt{z}$ is analytic you should pick a branch to start with and stick with that branch

Comment: @FShrike supposing that we do pick a branch then, how would i carry forward? I am stuck here.

Comment: For example it is possible to pick a branch of $\sqrt$ with only nonnegative real part (argument between $\pi/2,-\pi/2$) and you may as well do that. You should also notice that no choice of square root is analytic everywhere, as you will run into a branch cut somewhere

Comment: @FShrike would it be possible to post an answer on your part regarding this? I am still fairly new to complex analysis and am not as proficient in dealing with branch points(yet). This novice would appreciate it a lot, if you could take my workings and write up the conclusion. Thank you.

Comment: I may do later but I’m sorry to say I don’t have time right now. The polar form would certainly be much easier but I suspect it is cheating slightly: for the manual square root, I guess double check your calculations for sign errors (and stick to one branch! I suggest assert $a\ge0$ and sign$y=$sign$b$). You need to verify that: $$i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$On the interior of its non-branched domain (with my suggestion, this is on the set $z:\Re z\gt0$ with strict inequality)

Comment: * Correction: I was visualising the image of $f$, not the domain. The non-branched domain you need to verify CR on (with my choice of square root) is the set $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$

Comment: As a further exercise to complement my post, once you understand its contents, show that my definition of $f$ satisfies (outside the branch cut!): $$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2f(z)}$$By analogy with the usual square root derivative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}\newcommand{\del}{\partial}$I will only demonstrate that $\del_xu=\del_y v$ and leave the other verification as an exercise (it will be the same essentially but is good practice for you to do). I will consider the *principal branch* of the square root: this means I declare the square root of a number with positive imaginary part to have positive imaginary part, and a number with negative imaginary part to have a square root with negative imaginary part. This is taking the logarithmic-exponential square root with the declaration $-\pi\lt\mathrm{Arg}\le\pi$, if you know what I mean by that, and leaving a (logarithmic) branch cut along the nonpositive real axis. You already know how to solve the quadratic equations clearly ($x,y$ are any real numbers with $x+iy\notin(-\infty,0]$ because the sign term makes the expression there ambiguous): $$f:(x+iy)\mapsto\underset{u(x+iy)}{\underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}}}+i\cdot\underset{v(x+iy)}{\underbrace{\sgn(y)\cdot\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}}}$$Note that the sign term is very important!

It is a straightforward chain rule application to show that, when $x+iy\notin(-\infty,0]$ (this is our branch cut, so I won’t consider differentiability there - branching **is** important - see below): $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot\frac{\sgn(y)\cdot y}{\sqrt{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}},\quad y\neq0\end{align}$$

To show they are the same is equivalent to showing (when $y\neq0$): $$\begin{align}0&=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{\sgn(y)\cdot y}{\sqrt{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\\\iff0&=-\sgn(y)\cdot y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2-x^2}\\\iff0&=-\sgn(y)\cdot y+\sgn(y)\cdot y\end{align}$$Which is true. In the case $y=0$, note I have asserted $x\gt0$ for this branch and we see through L’Hôpital’s rule: $$\begin{align}\lim_{y\to0\\x\gt0}\partial_y v&=\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{2}}\lim_{y\to0}\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\\&=\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{2}}\lim_{y\to0}\sqrt{\frac{2y}{y(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}}}\\&=\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2x}\end{align}$$And we recover equality of partial derivatives in this case. $\blacksquare$

You will see that even if we allow complex numbers on the branch cut, $\del_x u=\del_y v$ (except possibly at $0$, I haven’t checked this case yet) but when you do the other half, as an exercise, in showing $\del_y u=-\del_x v$ (for $x+iy$ *not* on the branch cut $(-\infty,0]$), you will notice that fixing an $x\lt0$ and letting $y\to0$ (i.e. approaching the branch cut) does *not* give equality of derivatives (indeed, both sides of the resulting equations do not even have a limit, as would be expected from the geometric intuition of the image of $f$ “shearing” at the branch cut). So, the square root function I defined is analytic everywhere except for that cut, which is one of a few reasons why the $\pm$ notation you were using is problematic since branching has implications for when and where a function is differentiable.

Comment: thank you for this. Definitely would work out the rest on my own now.

Comment: You are very welcome. All that branching is at this level is something we do to avoid ambiguity, and we just need to be mindful of it when it comes to analyticity @F.N.

Comment: Ahh i see, definitely was confused with that. But now I have come to appreciate branches at a deeper level. I definitely needed this for my understanding. Thanks, again.

Comment: @F.N. And you’re welcome again! It was definitely worth seeing for myself to check that differentiability fails (due to the bad $\rm{sgn}$ term in the limits, rather like the absolute value failure to be differentiable) on the branch cut, and was a nice problem